Graphics tablet pressure not working in blender (Blender 4.0 / XP-Pen Deco01V2 / MacBook M1 Pro 2021)

Blender version: 4.0
Hardware: MacBook M1 Pro 2021
OS: Sonoma 14.5
Graphics tablet: XP-Pen Deco01V2 (drivers up to date)

The graphics tablet works fine with any other software, the drawing and the pressure works normally. I can also use the tablet in blender to click on stuff and if the pressure options for brushes etc are not selected I can use the tablet to draw/sculpt/move things.
However, when I tick the pressure options for radius and/or strength then nothing happens when I use the pen, I can only move it around the screen and still click on buttons but any brushes/sculpting tools etc do not do anything.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Have you tried tweaking the setting in your Preferences under Input > Tablet?

Yes I tried this and nothing in there solved the issue. However, I just found a solution (posted as answer below). Thank you for the suggestion though!

Every time i break down to go to BSE and write a post asking for help the issue somehow solves itself at the last second. Lmao.

To fix this, I opened the XPPen application with the tablet plugged in. Then I went to the Pen Settings tab.
At the top of the window there is an Application: section.
I pressed on the little "+" sign next to this section, selected the blender app and pressed "OK".
This fixed the issue with pressure.
